# How crash reporting tools really work

Tags: ios, crash

I know there are many crash reporting tools available in the market to collect crashes from the real devices. I would like to know how a crash reporting tool really collects its data?. Does it collect a crash report from the operating system once the crashed application launched again? or Does iOS allows the crash reporter to collect the data as soon as the app is crashed?.

It will be really great if somebody can explain what happens after an app is crashed or point me to right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System crash logs are located at `/private/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/` and (as far as I know) can't be accessed by the app directly. Most crash reporting tools will try to catch crashes and generate their own crash reports which will get stored locally and sent to a server for symbolication and processing.

You can take a look at the source for [KSCrash](https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash/), an open source crash reporting tool, to see how crashes are caught/stored/reported.

Comment: Apps can not access files outside of the sandbox, so they can't access the system generated crash reports either. Another open source solution that does that since a long time (safely) is PLCrashReporter and is widely used by lots of services: http://plcrashreporter.org